# SQL alchemy case insensitive sort order

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Hi Im trying to achieve a ascending sort order for particular columns in a sqlite database using sql alchemy, the issue im having is that the column I want to sort on has upper and lower case data and thus the sort order doesn't work correctly.

I then found out about func.lower and tried to incorporate this into the query but it either errors or just doesn't work, can somebody give me a working example of how to do a case insensitive ascending sort order using sql alchemy.

below is what I have so far (throws error):-

```
session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(func.lower(asc(history_sort_order_column))).all()
```

python 2.6.6
sql alchemy 0.7.10

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to *reverse* the ordering of your functions:

```
session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(asc(func.lower(history_sort_order_column))).all()
```

so lower *first*, then declare the ascending order.

Alternatively, change the collation to `NOCASE`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import collate

session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(asc(collate(history_sort_order_column, 'NOCASE'))).all()
```

which arguably is a better idea anyway.

I don't *think* the `ASC` is required, leaving that off simplifies your code somewhat:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import collate

session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(collate(history_sort_order_column, 'NOCASE')).all()
```

Comment: hmm i cant get this to work, as soon as i use collate or func.lower it stops the sort order completely and just defaults to sorting by id. the only way i can get this to work is by setting the collation for the column i have an issue with to NOCASE directly on the database and then ignore trying to do a case insensitive query, any thoughts on why this might not be working?

Comment: Probably you need to create an index for the collation order: `CREATE INDEX ResultsDBHistory ON tablename (history_sort_order_column COLLATE NOCASE)`.

Comment: No, the index will help speed things up but the collation should still work, see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

Comment: ive now created an index for the table i wanted and the column that ive been having issues with and im still getting the same result, it stops sorting as soon as i specify nocase or func.lower

Comment: Try to recreate the situation in the sqlite command line *only*. Does it work there? Then perhaps we have a SQLAlchemy or python `sqlite3` version issue here. But if it *doesn't* work in the command line either..

Comment: You can retrieve the SQL that SQLAlchemy generates by printing the `str()` result: `print str(session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(collate(history_sort_order_column, 'NOCASE')))` (note that you do *not* call `.all()` on it).

Comment: just for anybody else who reads this, it helped to have "echo=True" for create_engine in sql alchemy to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Stick to `func.lower()`. The NOCASE collation doesn't appear to be portable. On PostgresQL, I get: `collation "NOCASE" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist`.

Comment: @SamBull the question is tagged with `sqlite`; I used a database specific colation in my answer. See [this SO post for PG options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18807276/100297).

Comment: Fair enough, but I wasn't looking for a Postgres answer, I was looking for something portable. Just highlighting this to anybody else who wants to keep their code portable (which I'd imagine is a decent amount of sqlalchemy users, given that is half the reason to use sqlalchemy in the first place).

Comment: @SamBull SQLA is powerful enough that we can create hooks that’ll switch out collations depending on the target database, but collations themselves are just way too tied to a specific database environment for SQLA, or the limited scope of a SO answer, to make a generic solution feasible. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, but `func.lower()` is fine (it's also the method that the author of SQLA says he would choose, linked in the below answer).

Answer (score 2):

Michael Bayer (author of SQLAlchemy) addressed this topic in a [post on the sqlalchemy mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/ft3PIsNdCbw/m/6nh547TJ-OcJ):

> several ways to approach that, without it being built in as an expression. as a string:
>
> ```
> order_by=["name COLLATE NOCASE"]
> ```
>
> or just using the `lower()` function (to me this would be more obvious)
>
> ```
> order_by=[func.lower(table.c.name)]
> ```
>
> or you could use sql's `_CompoundClause`:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy.sql import _CompoundClause
>
> order_by = [_CompoundClause(None, table.c.name, "COLLATE NOCASE")]
> ```
>
> Id go with `func.lower()` probably...

There is also an example in the [documentation for `desc(column)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc):

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

stmt = select(users_table).order_by(desc(users_table.c.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of doing a sorting after the query.

```
res = session.query(ResultsDBHistory).all()
res.sort()  #sort as the way you like
```