# Case insensitive sort with peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

The following sort is case-sensitive:

```
MyModel.select().order_by(MyModel.name)
<class '__main__.MyModel'> SELECT t1."id", t1."name" FROM "mymodel" AS t1 ORDER BY t1."name" []
```

How do I add a `NOCASE` to make it case-insensitive?

Or is there another way to make it case-insensitive?

I couldn't find anything about it on the [documentation](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=order_by).

Comment: Would `MyModel.select().order_by(fn.Lower(MyModel.name))` work? That's how it works for SQLAlchemy.

Comment: For SQLite I see that Peewee also supports [custom collations](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html?highlight=collate#sqlite-ext-api-notes), which should be helpful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a SQL function (with the [`fn` helper](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=sql%20function#the-fn-helper)) to lowercase the model name:

```
MyModel.select().order_by(fn.Lower(MyModel.name))
```

For SQLite, you should be able to use a [custom collation](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#SqliteExtDatabase.collation) as well:

```
@db.collation()
def collate_case_insensitive(s1, s2):
    return cmp(s1.lower(), s2.lower())
```

The `@db.collation()` decorator provided by the [`SqliteExtDatabase()` subclass](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#sqlite-extensions) lets you register a custom collation function which you can then use to sort by:

```
MyModel.select().order_by(collate_case_insensitive.collation(MyModel.name))
```

Of course, SQLite already has a built-in [`NOCASE` collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) which should be used here instead, but to use it on must build a [`SQL()` object](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SQL) to include the raw SQL:

```
MyModel.select().order_by(Clause(MyModel.name, SQL('collate NOCASE')))
```

This echoes how case insensitive ordering works for SQLAlchemy: [SQL alchemy case insensitive sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567201/sql-alchemy-case-insensitive-sort-order)

Comment: Thanks. I finally understand what those `fn` are.